# Heroku could not connect to server: 'Connection refused' when deploying a Rails 3.2.3 app on cedar stack

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, cedar

Since yesterday it worked, but this morning, I can't figure out why, my app on heroku is unable to connect to the shared DB.
I can't even do a simple:

```
$ heroku run rake db:reset
```

(I'm on a cedar stack).
And this is the console trace dump:

```
** Invoke db:reset (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "ec2-107-22-222-231.compute-1.amazonaws.com" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1194:in `initialize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1194:in `new'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1194:in `connect'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:329:in `initialize'
...
Tasks: TOP => db:reset => environment
```

Any idea, please?

--**UPDATE**---

They just updated their status at https://status.heroku.com/ with incident 375: https://status.heroku.com/incidents/375

...I guess I just have to wait.

--**UPDATE**---

After 3 hours the error message changed into:

```
could not translate host name "ec2-107-22-222-231.compute-1.amazonaws.com" to address: Name or service not known (PG::Error)
```

At least now I know for sure that Heroku guys are working.

Comment: Any updates? I'm getting this error and not having any luck restarting. How did your issue get resolved?

Comment: I had the same issue, but it now [seems to be resolved](https://status.heroku.com/).  I can confirm my apps deployed on the Cedar stack are back up.

Comment: All you can to do, unfortunately, is to go [here](https://status.heroku.com/) and wait...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same problem here. It was working 'til yesterday.

> Dedicated production databases should be operational. **We're continuing recovery of shared
>   development databases and Crane and Kappa beta databases.** Varnish remains temporarily
>   disabled on the Bamboo HTTP stack.

Yeah, apparently just waiting is the answer here.